# Convert each factor in a column to to the one with the second highest frequency in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have following matrix with different strings in each column. The minimum number of different strings in one column is 2, some columns have up to 20 different strings, some columns have only two different strings. I would like to convert strings in columns with more than 2 different strings to strings which have the second highest frequency. To have in each column two different strings. There is always one factor with the highest frequency, but if there are two minor frequency strings with the same frequency then I want them to convert the string to either one of them, it doesn't matter which one.

My example matrix is:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "Y", "Y", "M", "M", 
"Y", "Y", "Z", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "X", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
r1 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "C" 
r2 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r3 "M"  "Y"  "X"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r4 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r5 "M"  "Z"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
r6 "F"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r7 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r8 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "B"  "B"  "E"
```

The desired output:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", "F", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
r1 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r2 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r3 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r4 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r5 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
r6 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r7 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r8 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "B"  "B"  "E"
```

I ordered each factor in each column in decreasing order so far. My code is:

```
apply(msa_protein.mat_2, 2, function(x) {
  sort <- sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: What in case if there are two with the second highest frequency? E.g. `M` and `Y` in col2 and col3.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter which one I would like to convert my factor to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `table`, `sort` it and replace everting what it not the most present with the second most.

```
apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) {
    tt <- sort(table(x), TRUE)
    if(length(tt) > 2) {x[x != names(tt)[1]] <- names(tt)[2]}
    x
})
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#r1 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
#r2 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
#r3 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
#r4 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
#r5 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
#r6 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
#r7 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
#r8 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "B"  "B"  "E"
```